# How can I write a tail recursive using Plpgsql language?

Tags: postgresql, recursion

Some post said the PostgreSQL's CTE is essentially iterations, I wonder how could I write a query using tail recursion and plpgsql language?

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH RECURSIVE zzz AS (
        SELECT 11::integer AS val
        UNION ALL
        SELECT CASE WHEN (zzz.val %2 = 1) THEN 3*zzz.val+1 ELSE zzz.val / 2 END AS val
        FROM zzz
        WHERE zzz.val <> 1
        )
SELECT * FROM zzz;
```